# Not able to find nearby location's results using coordinate $near statement in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to get results of nearby location from a specific point. By using a normal way of finding by ID, there is a result returned but when I am trying to find nearby location using the coordinates, no result is appearing. There wasn't any errors/warnings in my code but there wasn't any results too. What am I missing?

Model Schema

```
var locationSchema = new Schema({
    fb_location: String,
    coordinates:[]
});

var feed_postSchema = new Schema({
    content: String,
    location: [locationSchema],
    image: [{ type : String }],
    created_at: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
});

locationSchema.index({coordinates:'2dsphere'});
```

Server.js

```
app.get('/test_radar',function(request,response){
    Feed_Post.find( 
    {
        'location.coordinates' :
        {
            $near : 
            {
                coordinates: [100,5]
            },
            $maxDistance: 100
        }
    },function(err,ret){
        console.log(response.json(ret));
    })
});
```

Sample Database Data

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5620a3c2fde01a55065f4c3b"),
    "content" : "Test post",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-10-16T07:14:10.636Z"),
    "image" : [ ],
    "location" : [
            {
                    "fb_location" : "Malaysia",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5620a3c2fde01a55065f4c3c"),
                    "coordinates" : [
                            100,
                            5
                    ]
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
```

Note: I did set the $maxDistance to 100 * 1000. There is still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$near` operator requires a geospatial index.

If you want to define your location as a point using legacy coordinates you must have [2D index created](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/). Then you will be able to use `$near` operator in syntax you specified.

You created 2dsphere index so you must specify GeoJSON point in your query:

```
Feed_Post.find( 
    {
        'location.coordinates' :
        {
            $geometry: {
                 type: "Point" ,
                 coordinates: [ 100 , 5 ]
            },
            $maxDistance: 100
        }
    },function(err,ret){
        console.log(response.json(ret));
    })
```

Check [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) definition.

Comment: Yes you are right! I noticed my mistake. Thank you for helping me!